# Find liquid file name of cart page template

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am fairly new to Shopify development. I have to inject a few lines of code into the cart page liquid template using Asset Shopify API. This API accepts template file name as an argument. But I see that file name can be different for each theme. While one theme uses the name `cart.liquid`, another one uses `main-cart.liquid` and so on. Is there a way to get the current liquid file name of the cart page or even a product page using Shopify API?

Answer (score 0):

Template names are normalized. May be `cart` or `product` or `collection` and so on. `main-cart.liquid` is probably a section and not a template.